# Trying to format a connection string in Python - unable to replace with variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a connection string in Python - the goal is to have a list of tables/servers to access and it'll iterate through based on a list earlier.

I've got the query written (using `"""select * from """` worked) , but I cannot seem to get the connection string to behave. Yes. the "{SQL Server}" needs to be in curly-brackets.

```
server_name = "myservername"

#this doesn't work:
con_string = ('Driver={{SQL Server}};Server={server_name};Database={mydatabase};App=myappname;Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Nor does this

```
con_string = ('Driver={{SQL Server}};'
              'Server={};'.format(server_name)
              'Database=mydatabase;'
              'App=myappname;'  # It's not "application name"!
              'Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Nor this:

```
serverstring = 'Server={};'.format(server_name)
con_string = ('Driver={{SQL Server}};'
              '{serverstring}'
              'Database=mydatabase;'
              'App=myappname;'  # It's not "application name"!
              'Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To create a format string you need `f` at the beginning (so in your third example you should have `f'{serverstring}'`).

Comment: @rassar awesome!  If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) you need f at the beginning. So, for example, your third example should be:

```
serverstring = 'Server={};'.format(server_name)
con_string = ('Driver={{SQL Server}};'
              f'{serverstring}'
              'Database=mydatabase;'
              'App=myappname;'  # It's not "application name"!
              'Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Comment: This is a nice technique.  Please note that f-strings are only available in Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go.  The curly brackets are doubled up (as you have above) to escape themselves.  Is this what you're looking for?

Python 3.6 introduces new string formatting functionality (f-strings) which uses variable replacement.  But for those of us still on 3.5, this works nicely.

```
con_string = ('Driver={{SQL Server}};'
              'Server={svr};'
              'Database={db};'
              'App={app};'  
              'Trusted_Connection={tc}').format(svr='SERVER01', 
                                                db='MyDB', 
                                                app='MyApp',
                                                tc='Yes')
```

Here is the output:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER01;Database=MyDB;App=MyApp;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

Comment: thanks, that looks like that will work too!  Thanks!